# Getting form validation state inside angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am able to validate my form element 'name'd 'username'.

```
ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$invalid }"
```

But I cannot get this info inside a controller. Is this possible?

I want to do something like this:

```
mycontroller.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope){

    $scope.isusernameinvalid = $scope.form.username.$dirty && $scope.form.username.$invalid;
});
```

And use the isusernameinvalid (true/false) to toggle class

```
ng-class="{ 'has-error': isusernameinvalid }"
```

I know "form" is not a $scope variable, and hence inaccessible.

How do i access the validation state/class info over here?

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the form like this

```
<form name="formName"></form>
```

you should be able to access it in the controller via `$scope.formName`. However as always in angular you have to be careful about looking in the correct scope, so maybe set `ng-controller="mycontroller"` on the form tag or on some tag that contains the form tag if not done already.

It could also be that when the `$scope.isusernameinvalid = $scope.form.username.$dirty && $scope.form.username.$invalid;` code runs the form hasn't been initialized in the scope yet, so accessing it returns `undefined`. Declaring isuernameinvalid as a function instead should get around that:

```
$scope.isUsernameInvalid = function() {
    return $scope.form.username.$dirty && $scope.form.username.$invalid;
}
```

And then call it as a function in your `ng-class` directive.